# Why was artillery a more effective infantry support weapon on tanks than machine guns?

Tags: world-war-two, war, tanks

In supporting infantry, why are tanks equipped with large guns breach guns which seem more effective than assault vehicles with machine guns? For example, comparing the service of WW2 German Assault Guns vs Self Propelled Anti Air shows a great more assault guns were produced. Considering the effectiveness of the machine gun as an infantry support weapon was thoroughly demonstrated in the first world war (and given that the German WW2 squad was centered around it,) why was direct fire artillery produced so much more?

Comment: Machine guns aren't much good against enemy tanks, and artillery has more range.

Comment: Machine guns are also ineffective against fortified positions.

Comment: Machine guns were more effective against dispersed infantry standing in the open. Only problem, infantry tended to grab what ever cover they had in case of tank attack, not to mention trenches, fortifications  and all kind of anti-tank weapons deployed ever increasingly from early stages of WW2. Having a dual-purpose, capable of firing both AT and HE ammo became optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Answer (score 4):

> In supporting infantry, why are tanks equipped with large guns more effective than those with machine guns?

For one simple reason: a machine gun *already is* an infantry weapon. The infantry does not lack machine guns. They have plenty. What the infantry does lack is something that is able to destroy fortified strong points at range.

This is where the infantry support tanks come in. They don't need to be fast, they don't need any anti-tank capacities, but they need to pack a punch against static fortifications. Normally, that means high caliber direct fire weapons to destroy trenches, houses, bunkers and other local strongpoints that cannot be taken down by small arms fire.

Examples of those specialized infantry support tanks are the early German StuGs, but even before their deployment, the infantry support tanks like the early PzIV were equipped with high caliber direct fire guns for their role.

Tanks have machine guns for self defense against infantry. And if they lacked those, the German reports make special note of this and they were refitted. But those machine guns were used for defense.

For their actual offensive role of removing obstacles the infantry cannot remove with their infantry weapons, they used high caliber direct fire guns.

Answer (score 3):

A direct hit be an artillery shell is usually much more effective than a burst from a machine gun. For the infantry, the MG has two advantages compared to the howitzer, it can be carried by a few men and the ammunition is light enough to carry several hundred rounds.

Before WWII, the main roles of the tank were understood to be the breakthrough through infantry defenses and the exploitation of such a breakthrough. The Brits called that the [infantry tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infantry_tank) and [cruiser tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruiser_tank) roles. The defense against tanks was left to anti-tank guns, either self-propelled or towed. In part, that was due to the technological limitations of the era. Tanks were relatively small and lightweight and could not carry heavy guns.

WWII saw both an escalation in the size of the "medium" tank -- what would be called "main battle tank" later on -- and the introduction of workarounds to put a bigger gun onto a relatively small tank chassis. Those were tank destroyers and assault guns.

After WWII, the Americans concluded that their old doctrine was in error and added anti-tank defense to the roles of their main battle tanks. One might note that the US and the Soviet Union were able to produce true tanks in far greater numbers than Germany produced their cheaper substitutes.

So modern main battle tanks mount a large, high-velocity cannon for their anti-tank role. It is relatively cheap to add a dozen HE shells for infantry support, **as well** as a coaxial MG with several thousand rounds of ammunition.

Comment: Just a thing: I don't think the AMericans conclude their old doctrine was in error: they just considered peacetime and technological evolution allowed to reconsider the old doctrine, which was time-constraint (means that the Sherman did not use all technoogies available)